# VS Code Remote - windows path with whitespace in it - ssh error

Tags: ssh, visual-studio-code, vscode-remote

I want to connect to my server via ssh. I have installed the remote dev package in VS Code, I can connect via ssh in VSC terminal, but not via the ssh 'panel'. When I do so, I get:

```
[10:45:40.155] Spawned 9044
[10:45:40.266] > local-server> Spawned ssh: 7472
[10:45:40.292] stderr> OpenSSH_7.9p1, OpenSSL 1.1.1a  20 Nov 2018
[10:45:41.149] stderr> debug1: Server host key: ecds...56 SHA256:5SDO....
[10:45:41.183] stderr> 'C:\Users\Name' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
[10:45:41.183] stderr> operable program or batch file.
[10:45:41.186] stderr> Host key verification failed.
[10:45:41.189] > local-server> ssh child died, shutting down
[10:45:41.197] Local server exit: 0
[10:45:41.198] Received install output: OpenSSH_7.9p1, OpenSSL 1.1.1a  20 Nov 2018
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-s.....
'C:\Users\Name' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
Host key verification failed.
```

As you can see, I have C/users/Name Surname/... user which causes trouble - it gets parsed with whitespace between Name and Surname

it happens probably when it tries to reach this:

```
[10:45:40.091] Local server env: {"DISPLAY":"1","ELECTRON_RUN_AS_NODE":"1","SSH_ASKPASS":"c:\\Users\\Name Surname\\.vscode\\extensions\\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.50.0\\out\\local-server\\askpass.bat","VSCODE_SSH_ASKPASS_NODE":"C:\\Users\\Name Surname\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Microsoft VS Code\\Code.exe","VSCODE_SSH_ASKPASS_MAIN":"c:\\Users\\Name Surname\\.vscode\\extensions\\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.50.0\\out\\askpass-main.js","VSCODE_SSH_ASKPASS_HANDLE":"\\\\.\\pipe\\vscode-ssh-askpass-1e1200d27-sock"}
```

My question is, what can I do about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the extension settings search for: @ext:ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh Path

Then under Path specify an absolute path for an ssh installation. On my windows install it was located here: C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\ssh.exe

Comment: Hi I can't locate the Path to enter the C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\ssh.exe in VSC. Appreciate if you can guide to locate it in VSC. Thanks.